# Why these two optimization problems are equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$:
    \begin{align}
  \min_{\beta, z}\|y-z\|_2^2+v(z-X\beta)
\end{align}
is equivalent of the problem,
    \begin{align*}
  \min_{v\in\mathbb{R}^n} \|y-v\|_2^2 \text{ subject to } X^Tv = 0
\end{align*}

I was told that these two problems are essentially the same problem. I realized that $v$ is actually in the null space of $X$ and it seems that $z$ is in the column space of $y$? What I am confusing is why am I optimizing the same thing as finally I can achieve $v^* = y - z^*$ at the optimality.

Any explanation from the linear algebra's view?

Comment: What's $v(z-X\beta)$ supposed to mean?